# Convert file for XLS to TXT format

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, file-format

I renamed a .xls file to .txt file but the .txt file shows like this:

> öRn÷åËþEõZ;zûÕÃ·IÉD;Üÿêá¾ú‡×**4u\çBq&?!€¨(ˆô‰/t/ª§‹'Oý?WïçþJ®½ãÁÁ|DiæEÇ’IŠ›ðä/\$r'Ù¡`îê?|ÕÝê®²¸ó—QG¦çåÎŠ/–×ÒÏpQP~Q|å?‘ÈpÖ‘»ëËß62
>   Š/zaqçÎÖ©ú•ênÆ›WÚ·«àÙ}S«ˆº/~Ø×:U”¥‡7îTísvçùòl!ý0ýá»êéqx[T¯ß¿ø1
>   ¼ð…P`ïXáÃñ}ý«Å'gK)á*ÐÒm¦ŽØ™¯Püä©ïªÇÃ‹‹—‹U¡Jq5ÿ‚Šÿò6qúßŸX½ûuqi&×6êÞç~°ðÄÜ‹Òý¥Ÿø…cŸEão(ýNÖáÛ«*

How can I get the same data as in an .xls file?

Comment: Do you mean, you changed the file's extension, i.e. renamed it? That wouldn't change its content then and you can just rename it back.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done from within Excel by saving the file in a **specific** text format.

In Excel the process would be

- Click on the Orb or press <kbd>F12</kbd> to select Save As
- In the Save As Type box select one of the valid Text Document Format
- Enter a name for the new file
- Click Save, and on the warning that appears select continue.

The [How To Geek](https://superuser.com/users/4102/the-how-to-geek) has an article [here](http://blogs.howtogeek.com/mysticgeek/2008/08/03/convert-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-a-tab-delimited-text-file/) on how to save an Excel document as a Tab-Delimited text file for example.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not 100% clear, but I'm guessing you want the data stored in a pure textual file, rather than something only Excel could read (If I'm wrong, ignore my answer).

You can save the file from within Excel into another format. From the **File menu** (or the big button on the ribbon in Excel 2007), choose "**Save As**". Then choose "**Text (tab delimited) *.txt**" in the "save as type" drop down list. Give it a new name and save.

Good luck =8-)

Answer (score 1):

If the question relates to coding you can use [xls converter](http://www.devtriogroup.com) for .NET. But it just for programmers. There is .net component for reading excel files.